# javascript web data connector doesn't work with optional url parameters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use javascript URLSearchParameters in which a user can type in certain fields to get particular data sets in json file.

The URLSearchParameter seems to work for when you select certain fields but it does not seem to parse the URL correctly in certain situations.

For Example symbol and apikey is a required field.
Optional fields are start date and end date.

When I type in symbol and apikey and leave all of the optional fields empty, the script breaks. When I type any one of the optional fields, it works. My code is provided below. My schema is not like this but below is an example that is similar. I have more optional fields in my final code but if all of them are empty my code continues to break.

Also I would like to know if there is any simpler way to write this code as I'm repeating the code in if else statements and I am repeating the code the same way.

```
(function() {
    // Create the connector object
    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

    // Define the schema
    myConnector.getSchema = function(schemaCallback) {
        var cols = [{
            id: "symbol",
            alias: "symbol",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "date",
            alias: "date",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.date
        }
    ];
        var tableSchema = {
            id: "My data",
            alias:"My daily data ",
            columns: cols
        };
        schemaCallback([tableSchema]);
    };
    // Download the data
    myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
        var dataObj = JSON.parse(tableau.connectionData);
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams (dataObj);
        const apiCall = `https://mywebsite/getMyData.json?${searchParams}`; 
        $.getJSON(apiCall, function(resp) {
            var feat = resp.results,
                tableData = [];
            // Iterate over the JSON object
            for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
                tableData.push({
                    "symbol": feat[i].symbol,
                    "date": feat[i].date,
                });
            }
            table.appendRows(tableData);
            doneCallback();
        });
    };
    tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);
    // Create event listeners for when the user submits the form
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submitButton").click(function() 
        {
            if ($('#symbol').val().trim().length == 0 || $('#apikey').val().trim().length == 0)
            {
                $('#errorMsg').show().html("Symbol  and APi key can't be blank.");
            }
            else if ($('#start-date').val().trim().length == 0){
                var dataObj = {
                    apikey: $('#apikey').val().trim(),
                    symbol: $('#symbol').val().trim(),
                    endDate: $('#end-date').val().trim(),
                 }
                 tableau.connectionData = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
                 tableau.connectionName = "My Data";
                 tableau.submit();  
            }
            else if ($('#end-date').val().trim().length == 0){
                var dataObj = {
                    apikey: $('#apikey').val().trim(),
                    symbol: $('#symbol').val().trim(),
                    startDate: $('#start-date').val().trim(),
                 }
                 tableau.connectionData = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
                 tableau.connectionName = "My Data";
                 tableau.submit();  
            }
            else if ($('#start-date').val().trim().length == 0 && $('#end-date').val().trim().length == 0){
                var dataObj = {
                    apikey: $('#apikey').val().trim(),
                    symbol: $('#symbol').val().trim(),
                    type: $('#type').val().trim(),
                 }
                 tableau.connectionData = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
                 tableau.connectionName = "My Data";
                 tableau.submit();  
            }
            else{
                var dataObj = {
                    apikey: $('#apikey').val().trim(),
                    symbol: $('#symbol').val().trim(),
                    startDate: $('#start-date').val().trim(),
                    endDate: $('#end-date').val().trim(),
                };
                tableau.connectionData = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
                tableau.connectionName = "My Data";
                tableau.submit();  

            }


        });
    });
})();
```